# Unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, virtualenv

I am running Ubuntu LTS and I'm getting errors when trying to do some of my pip install stuff, like scrapy for example. This is the error I get:

```
Unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory
Error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I'm installing pip within a virtualenv. I tried to install build essentials with the following command but I still get the same error:

```
apt-get -y install build-essential
```

Can anyone help me understand where I have gone wrong please?

EDIT - A bit more information:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-164-8-155:/var/log$ gcc -v
The program 'gcc' can be found in the following packages:
 * gcc
 * pentium-builder
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Comment: What was the output of your `apt-get -y install build-essential`?  You definitely do not have the gcc executable installed.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

NOTE: from your `gcc -v` output
Try: `sudo apt-get install` *selected package*

`sudo apt-get install gcc`

Comment: That message indicates that the command (`gcc`) wasn't found, but that Ubuntu can suggest a package that provides it (the `gcc` package in this case).